# ROS Network through firewall

Tags: ros, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I have to say I'm a newbie working with networks. I have the following problem:

- I have a remote machine where my roscore and some other nodes are running.
- I need to run the nodes in my laptop with that machine as ROS master but there is a firewall between them.
- I can connect to a server (in the same network as the remote machine) and from that server to the remote machine. So I can skip the firewall...

So, how can I stablish the connection between the two machines?

Somebody told me that I can use ssh -L to make a tunnel for a specific port, but not for all... And this ROS tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup is talking about OpenVPN that I don't have idea how to use it...

Thanks in advance,

Josep

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43913/ros-network-through-firewall/) by [Jep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2367/jep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2012-09-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yizheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22954/yizheng/) on 2016-02-07**:
Hi Josep, I have a similar problem as you did, can you tell me how to solve it ? I've followed the how to page on openvpn site, but I get tls handshake error when I try to connect the server from the client. This is my post http://answers.ros.org/question/225995/how-to-set-ros_master_uri-to-a-port-of-a-router/

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the NetworkSetup wiki page says, if you're behind a firewall, the best solution is to use a VPN. OpenVPN's [HOWTO](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) page should help get you started.

If the firewall is provided by something like a home router, you could also set the DMZ host to the IP address of the computer you want to be able to access.

Since ROS uses lots of arbitrary ports, ssh tunneling is not a realistic solution.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2